# Как проверять тип у хандлера кнопки React.js TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

В компоненте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит событие onClick и вызывается метод this.renderFormsSteps();

Все хорошо, но компилятор ругается на

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'
```

Проще говоря, я не знаю как задавать типы хандлеру и проверять их...

вот код компонента:

```
    interface RegistrationProps {
    login: LoginState 
}

interface RegistrationState {
    login: string, 
    name: string, 
    lastName: string, 
    activeStep: number,
}

export class Registration extends React.Component<RegistrationProps, RegistrationState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            login: '',
            name: '',
            lastName: '',
            activeStep: 1
        }
    }

    private renderSteps = (step: number) => {
        const classNameStep1 = step === 1 ? "activeStep" : "step";
        const classNameStep2 = step === 2 ? "activeStep" : "step";
        const classNameStep3 = step === 3 ? "activeStep" : "step";

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div className={classNameStep1}>Логин и имя</div>
            <div className={classNameStep2}>Персональные данные</div>
            <div className={classNameStep3}>Пароль</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    private renderFormsSteps = (step: number) => {
       if (step === 1) {
           return (
               <div>
                   <div>Логин и имя</div>
                   <div><button onClick={this.handleNextStepButton(step)} type="button" className="btn btn-dark">Next</button></div> 
               </div>
           );
       } else if (step === 2) {
           return (
               <div>Персональные данные</div>
           );
       } else if(step === 3) {
           return (
               <div>Пароль</div>
           );
       } else {
           return (
               <div>...</div>
           );
       }
    }

    private handleNextStepButton = (nextStep: number)  => {
        this.setState({activeStep: nextStep});
    }

    public render() {
        const {activeStep} = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
            <div className="registrationHead">
                <Link to="/"> Вернуться </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="registrationTitle">Регистрация</div>
            {this.renderSteps(activeStep)}
            {this.renderFormsSteps(activeStep)}
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

Если что (зависимости):

"@types/react": "^16.8.23",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
 "typescript": "^3.5.3"
```

Comment: Проблема здесь не в типах, а в неправильном использовании функций. Вы присваиваете `onClick` не саму функцию (обработчик), а результат ее вызова/выполнения. `this.handleNextStepButton` ничего не возвращает, поэтому компилятор и ругается.

Comment: @hindmost , подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно присвоить саму функцию, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку получилось поменять значение activeStep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это часто бывает, компилятор сообщает не о реальной проблеме, а ее следствии. Ваша проблема в том что вы присваиваете `onClick` не саму функцию (`this.handleNextStepButton`), а результат ее вызова/выполнения. `this.handleNextStepButton` ничего не возвращает, от этого и ошибка.

Проще всего решить эту проблему с помощью замыкания. Например так:

```
...
private handleNextStepButton = (nextStep: number) => () => {
    this.setState({activeStep: nextStep});
}
...
```

Либо можно вообще избавиться от метода `handleNextStepButton` (тем более что он используется только раз), и подставить замыкание (с вызовом `this.setState`) в `onClick` напрямую:

```
...
<div><button onClick={ () => {this.setState({activeStep: step})} } type="button" className="btn btn-dark">Next</button></div> 
...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Также ответ на мой вопрос и теория есть в этой главе Реакта https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: В общем, бедный typeScript тут совсем не причем...